# Widget internal hooks and functions

Tags: plugin-development, widgets, api

I am working on my 1st plugin, of some ideas to re-do the interface to how widget's are manage d and organized. Anyhow.

I am struggling to get this information, either that or understand it.

1. Create a list in array, preferrably of all widgetized areas and their id.
2. Are there functions or methods to allow add/remove such widgetized areas, without editing the theme functions page?

I've looked at the widget api, but I think that my scope is beyound what is available there, is there any additional information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `default-widgets.php` and `widgets.php` files from `wp-includes` folder. You'll find a couple of filters and actions there which will help you. You're gonna have to try them out, they aren't documented.

`Create a list in array, preferrably of all widgetized areas and their id.`
- Use the filter `sidebar_widgets`, it will give you the ids of all widgets and their corresponding areas as an array. [This post](http://blog.rutwick.com/show-or-hide-a-wp-widget-only-on-specific-pages) will give you an idea of how you can use `sidebar_widgets` filter.